# Ant move, copy tasks failing on mapped drives in jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins, mapped-drive

I have an ant file which has move and copy tasks. The source and destination locations are on the mapped network drive `R:\`. When I run them on the command prompt the build is successful but when I configure it as a job in `Jenkins`, the tasks are failing with the below console output.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\admin\.jenkins\jobs\CopyTask\workspace\build.xml:24: R:\dest does not exist.

Total time: 0 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Both the standalone build and Jenkins build are under the same user credentials.

I have looked in the the questions [copy in ANT throws java.io.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194364/copy-in-ant-throws-java-io-filenotfoundexception) and
[Ant Copy Task: Failed to copy due to java.io.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344930/ant-copy-task-failed-to-copy-due-to-java-io-filenotfoundexception) but it didn't help me solve the issue.

**EDIT**

Jenkins service was running under local system account and in Jenkins app, I was using "Jenkins's own user database" for Security Realm. I had created a user called "admin" with all the permissions granted. After looking in to this [link](http://jenkins-le-guide-complet.batmat.cloudbees.net/html/sect-windows-service.html#fig-hudson-windows-service-config), I installed [Active Directory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+Plugin) and used an administrator account credentials to start the Jenkins service. But still I am getting the below error message

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\admin\.jenkins\workspace\CopyTask\build.xml:11: 
Failed to copy C:\Users\admin\FldrToCopy\data.7z to 
R:\data.7z due to failed to create the parent directory for R:\data.7z

Total time: 0 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: has neither `ant -verbose` nor `ant -debug` given you more information?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pxPTeHS1 this is the console I got using verbose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, the system account you're using doesn't have this mapped drive. Before copying, try to map the drive through the Windows [net use](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) command. In Jenkins, you can run this in your build steps as a shell command before you execute your Ant script.

I don't have a Windows machine in front of me, but it should look something like this:

```
net use R: /delete
net use R: /persistent:yes \\windows\share\path
```

You want to do the `net use R: /delete` first to remove any already existing mapping.

If this doesn't work, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4763324/368630). This will help you create a mapped drive to your system account that always exist.

Comment: Since I had already mapped the drive from the GUI, I didn't think of that. It should be `net use R: /persistent:yes \\windows\share\path` by the way.

Comment: If you mapped the drive from the GUI, it is only for that particular user. I'll fix my syntax. It's hard to remember if you don't use it all the time, and not having a Windows machine in front of me meant I couldn't test it.

Comment: Please notice, that you need to use the upper scripts in a cmd with admin privileges, otherwise it will not be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

What user account is Jenkins running as?  If it's running as the SYSTEM account, then it probably can't see the mapped drive.  Take a look at [Map a network drive to be used by a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service) for some ideas.

Or perhaps you could use the UNC path instead of the mapped drive?

Comment: Using UNC path does the job, but I need to do it only through Mapped drive. Plz see the edit for more information. Thanks